# Minimum server requirements for a django project

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment, nginx, gunicorn

I want to deploy a django project with the following stack: Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL.

I was thinking to use a [Linode 1GB](https://www.linode.com/pricing) server which has:

- 1 GB RAM
- 1 CPU Core
- 24 GB SSD Storage
- 2 TB Transfer
- 40 Gbit Network In
- 125 Mbit Network Out

At the beginning I expect to have very low traffic. **Is a Linode 1GB enough or should I choose a better one with more RAM/cores?** I would like to choose the minimum one that fits my needs now and upgrade as the traffic grows.

*Bonus general question: How can I calculate the server requirements for a specific stack and traffic?*

Comment: It is an interesting question, but probably better on super user or something similar, as more about hardware than programming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is a Linode 1GB enough

Well, it'll all run on that. You don't say what sort of load you want to support though.

So - here's what you want to do.

1. Add some basic monitoring into the mix - mem/cpu/disk/network traces + record them.
2. Script your server so you can go from an empty vm to working system automatically. There's all sorts of stuff out there - puppet/chef/vagrant. You're already using python, so [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/index.html) might suit you.
3. Now test it. Fire up a local VM (or hire a Linode one by the hour) and stress-test it.
4. Rent a bigger one + test that too.

Now you know what size VM you need and when you'll need to switch.

Comment: An open source load testing tool. https://locust.io/. I think, this will be useful.

Comment: https://github.com/locustio/locust/